# how to backup cell phone contacts to gmail, and view them on pc

Tags: contacts

i have synced my phone LG E975K (whatever that means!)
i have tried to save contacts to my gmail account. (gmail account only shows email contacts on - not the phone numbers from my smartphone)
i basically dont know how to save information from my smart phone to my computer.
i need a button repaired on my smart phone, and i dont want to lose all my information when i take the phone in to be repaired...

i believe there is a way to import or export? but my phone threatens me with possible loss of information, so i am scared to try it.

i see there is an option of merging contacts when i looked for info online, but my phone doesnt offer that option

i want to save all my phone information in gmail.
i dont know how to do it,
and i dont know how to find it if it has saved it
and i dont know how to restore it to the phone after it has been repaired, if information is lost....

can anyone help, but give instructions in layman's terms or explanations........

Comment: Can you check whether the synch of contacts/People is enabled under Settings?
Settings -> Accounts (google) -> click on Synch -> contacts is checked ? and Synch is successful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Settings > Accounts - Google > Tap on your account >`. Now
   select the checkbox for `Contacts` and see what is the last synced
   date and time shown below.
2. Now login to your Google account and go to Google contacts. You will
   be able to see all the synced contacts

From Panel:
Make sure you export all your contacts from sim/phone to gmail account via phonebook, then sync contact again through the direction given above.

Comment: thank you.have done all the above. still only shows my email addresses and not the telephone numbers from my LG..  any other suggestions? :(

Comment: In `Sync` list, do you see anything like `People Details` ? Try syncing that too.

Comment: I know this is an old post that the bot brought back to life, but just throwing my two cents in. Make sure to save contacts as gmail contacts when adding them as a contact. If they are labeled as a phone contact, I am pretty sure they don't get synced. Recently had to help a coworker out with this.